# List of users being suspended

Tags: support, account-suspension

I wonder how I can check a user is suspended or not. I think the only way is to go to the user's profile to check if he is suspended, is that correct? Other than that, can I find the list of the users who are currently being suspended?

Comment: On a related note, **Gone** should be eligible to rejoin us in just a couple short months!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the fact that there is no list of currently suspended users accessible to normal users is a conscious design choice.  See the following MSO questions:

- [How do I see a list of all suspended users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25395/214632)
- [How do I figure out who's been banished to the penalty box recently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9808/214632)

(To check whether a specific user is suspended you can check their user profile, as you noted.)

Answer (score 13):

Check the Database for [Suspended Users](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/104095/suspended-users), but be aware that DB dumps are not the same as real time.

Comment: I would like to note that, even taking into account that the data.SE data is not fully up to date, this query can generate both false positives and false negatives.

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing this out, @ArthurFischer ...

Comment: I wonder what one has to do to get a three years network wide suspension.

Comment: @AsafKaragila if your comment is a question, let me ask: *What have you tried?* Just kidding...

Comment: draks, nothing yet. I suppose that trolling at religion website and posting many offensive posts on many offensive websites would do the trick. But three years? That's a big one. You'd have to layout a six years plan for genocide or something.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Network-wide suspensions are very rare, and usually not used as punishment for misbehaviour. Misbehaving on one site will not affect your accounts on any other site, though the mods there will likely have much less patience if your misbehave there as well. Network-wide suspensions are mostly used if a user is just abusing SE sites and it is the easiest way to stop them.